# Open KML Photos In Default Desktop Application

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have created a KML file containing several thousand placemarks.  The description contains a simple HTML  tag referencing a location on local disk, pointing to a JPG photograph.  The photos display in the popup balloons properly.

I would like for users of Google Earth 7 to be able to click on the displayed photo and have their default JPG file type handler application open and display the photo file.

I have tried enclosing the `<img>` tag with an `<a href>` tag, using the notation `href="file://photos\technician01\photo1.jpg"`, but I can't get the behaviour I am looking for (no external viewer is ever spawned).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

**Update**
Here's a complete block of HTML I have attempted to achieve the described functionality:

```
<a href=" photos\technician01\August 19, 2013\DSCN0596.jpg">
  <table style="width:800px;height:600px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="photos\technician01\August 19, 2013\DSCN0596.jpg" style="height:auto; width:100%"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>`
```

Comment: a little more code would be helpful...

Comment: I should mention as well that replacing the `<img>` tag with a piece of text yields the same results; no external application is spawned when clicking in the hyperlink.

Comment: i'm curious how the spaces in your folder names are affecting things...are you able to adjust the folder names (actual folder names as well as the corresponding path in the `src` tag)

Comment: you might try replacing each space in the `src` path with `%20`

Comment: Yeah, I thought spaces would be the problem and replaced them all with %20, but with the same result (also noticed the leading space in the `<a href=` value and removed it; no effect).  Do different rules govern the validity of the `<img src=` as opposed to the `<a href=` values?  The photos display as expected in the balloons (`<img src=`), which is why I was hesitant to blame to path name (they are identical, with spaces, commas, whatever).
Is it possible that this is a security restriction?  Has anyone seen this functional in the wild?

Comment: is this the html you are including in the description tag of the kml?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This HTML code is placed in a `<description>` tag, within a `<Placemark>` tag.

Comment: Ah. Ok.  Just added an answer below that will hopefully help.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the following to work

```
  <Placemark>
    <name>Simple placemark</name>
    <description>
      Attached to the ground. Intelligently places itself at the
      height of the underlying terrain.
      <![CDATA[<div align="center"><table width="500"><tr><td>
        <a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Logan_Rock_Treen_closeup.jpg">
          <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Logan_Rock_Treen_closeup.jpg" width="500" height="373">
        </a>
      </td></tr></table></div>]]>
    </description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-122.0822035425683,37.42228990140251,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

Maybe that helps?

Comment: Web links seem to work fine as href targets (default web browser spawns, web page loads), but to link to a file on local disk, I'm still stuck.

Comment: Ah.  That may not actually be doable.  HTML prevents opening your default file handlers for security reasons (see this [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page) for a better explanation)